# real-time water effects without shaders

Tags: graphics, 3d

Im looking for a way to render decent-looking water on non-PC based hardware.

The platform has following limitations:

- absence of hw shaders
- absence of hw z-buffer

Available primitives are:

- gouraud shaded triangles (with alpha)
- textured triangles (with alpha)

Effects that are wanted:

- transparency
- caustics
- small waves/ripples
- refraction

Ideas I came up with:

- animated/semi-transparent texture
- bump-map/normal map
- reflections by projecting world on X-Z plane

Before I actually go off prototyping some of these points, I wanted to see if anyone else has had similar experience, better suggestions, links to code samples, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of tricks that used to be used on old fixed function 3D hardware on the PC. Does your hardware support fixed function environment mapping? Multi-texturing and programmable blend stages? With just single texturing and no support for more complicated fixed function effects your options are limited but pre-shader hardware with slightly more sophisticated fixed function pipelines gives you quite a few possibilities. Fixed function environment mapping can be used to get some nice basic water effects for example.

NVIDIA's developer site used to be a good resource for all kinds of effects on old fixed function hardware but many of those articles don't seem to be available any more. You might be able to track some of them down by looking at old versions of the site from the Internet Archive. Other places to look for ideas are old GDC presentations and old articles on Gamasutra.com as well as some of the older Game Programming Gems books.